# Distance between a point and a line in 3D

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

This is the question I am trying to solve:
Let $V = (0,3,2)$ and $A = (-1,0,1).$ Let $P$ be the point on the line passing through $A$ with direction vector $(1,1,1)$ that is closest to $V.$ Find the distance between $V$ and the line.

This is the diagram:
[image]

I know that P is (2/3, 5/3, 8/3) and that $\overrightarrow{AP}$ is (5/3, 5/3, 5/3). However, I am still having trouble answering this question because I don't even know how to start. Any advice/help?

Comment: Though this is not the typical way of solving the problem, at this point, you can find the magnitude of $\vec{AP}$ and the magnitude of $\vec{AV}$ then apply Pythagorean's Theorem to find the magnitude of $\vec{PV}$.

Comment: @Crystal Thank you! I took your suggestion, and I found out that AV is (1,3,1). I got the magnitude of PV as (5sqrt33)/3. I just wanted to know if this is correct?

Comment: Not quite, make sure you are subtracting $|\vec{AP}|^2$ from $|\vec{AV}|^2$ when you apply Pythagorean's Theorem. You should get $\sqrt{\frac{8}{3}}$.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out my mistake, but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard way to find the distance without having to calculate the closest point $P$ is as follows:

Project $\vec{AV} = (1,3,1)$ onto the direction vector $d=(1,1,1)$:

$$\left(\vec{AV}\cdot \frac d{|d|}\right)\frac d{|d|}$$

Then, you have

$$|\vec{PV}|^2 = |\vec{AV}|^2 - \left|\left(\vec{AV}\cdot \frac d{|d|}\right)\frac d{|d|}\right|^2 =  |\vec{AV}|^2 -\frac{|\vec{AV}\cdot d|^2}{|d|^2}$$

$$= 11 - \frac{25}{3}\Rightarrow |\vec{PV}|=\sqrt{\frac 83}$$